# EXCEL: Is there a way to call and replicate particular data from a different worksheet dependent on the result of a different formula?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, formulas

I've got a weather data workbook but with all the background processes on worksheets that are hidden. It currently only supports 4 cities - NYC for example - each city having it's own worksheet and I need to extend it. When the location is chosen (through a drop down menu), the data is called from the respective sheet and goes on from there. I currently use this formula to look up that cities data:

```
    =IF('Choose Variables'!$D$10="NYC - New York",NYC!G9,
IF('Choose Variables'!$D$10="Santiago",Santiago!G9,
IF('Choose Variables'!$D$10="London",London!G9,
IF('Choose Variables'!$D$10="Rio de Janiero",'Rio'!G9,
"Data not available"))))
```

Then drag this formula down ~4800 and across 3 cells to get the various data needed.

This works fine, but as you can imagine, adding ~50 more cities is going to be arduous to say the least. I've had a google and =Vlookup, =lookup etc won't help me.

TLDR; Is there a way to call and replicate particular data from a different worksheet dependent on the result of a different formula? This will be to pass on quite quickly and I don't fancy learning Macros just for this, but any other suggestions would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NYC` is problematic because the text "NYC - New York" doesn't match the worksheet name NYC (unlike your other examples) but if you can make all those match you can use `INDIRECT` function to convert a text value in a cell to a valid reference, e.g.

`=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&'Choose Variables'!$D$10&"'!G9"),"Data not available")`

one problem with INDIRECT is that you make the G9 value into a text value so it isn't "draggable" - if you want G9 to increment when you drag down or across change to this

`=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&'Choose Variables'!$D$10&"'!"&CELL("address",G9)),"Data not available")`

If you can't make the text in D10 always exactly match the sheet name (or you don't want to) then you can always make a two column table (name it **table**) with the cell text in the first column, e.g. **NYC - New York** and the sheet name in the next, e.g. **NYC** then you can use VLOOKUP like this

`=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&VLOOKUP('Choose Variables'!$D$10,table,2,0)&"'!"&CELL("address",G9)),"Data not available")`

Comment: This looks brilliant, thank you. Would you mind clarifying what you mean when you say "address"? If I C+V that formula into my sheet, it uses the G9 from the same sheet as I'm currently on.